# Why is `split-window` needed to get a shell in window 0 when sourcing commands?

Tags: tmux

I restore common setups for my project with something equivalent to this:

```
setup_file=myproj.tmux
tmux new-session "tmux source-file $setup_file"
```

I would normally assume that starting a new session and then sourcing commands from `$setup_file` would be equivalent to manually executing those tmux commands in a new shell, but it's not! The difference is that when sourcing, no shell seems to be created in window 0, so when I execute `neww` this creates a window 1, but window 0 is missing when everything has been setup. To hack around this I execute `split-window`, but I do not understand why I need to do this. Clues?

**myproj.tmux**

```
# window 0 - cli
rename-window 'cli';
split-window # not sure why this is needed to get a shell. Otherwise there is no window 0!

# window 1 - main window in the left pane and 3 minor windows in the right pane
neww
rename-window 'tools'
send-keys 'nvim' C-m  # editor
split-window -h -p 40 # build window (webpack, etc)
split-window -v -p 80             # cli
split-window -v -p 50             # test runner?
select-pane -L; # select the left pane; nvim
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but window 0 is missing when everything has been setup

Without the questionable `split-window`, the code that runs in only pane in window 0 is `tmux source-file $setup_file` (with `$setup_file` already expanded by the original shell). When everything is set up this command terminates, so the only pane terminates, so the window terminates.

It would be different with

```
tmux new-session "tmux source-file '$setup_file'; '$SHELL'"
```

Note this command is quoted "better" than your original command, but still not properly quoted. In Bash proper quoting can be achieved thanks to `${var@Q}`:

```
tmux new-session "tmux source-file ${setup_file@Q}; ${SHELL@Q}"
```

Comment: That makes total sense. Thanks.